# What is the difference between setQuery() and setSource() in elastic SearchRequestBuilder?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

From looking at people's code, it seems that you can set the query using `setSource()`/`setExtraSource()` or `setQuery()`.

According to documentation:

```
public SearchRequestBuilder setQuery(String query)
```

Constructs a new search source builder with a raw search query.

```
public SearchRequestBuilder setSource(String source)
```

Sets the source of the request as a json string. Note, settings anything other than the search type will cause this source to be overridden, consider using `setExtraSource(String)`.

What is the difference between Query and Source? 
When do I use each?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think setQuery(string query) used to set directly the term searched. setSource(String source) needs a valid JSON to request at Elasticsearch (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchRequestBuilder.java#L835).

So you use setSource if you want build the search request JSON by youself.